# OUTPUT INSERTED Id/SCOPE_IDENTITY() returns null in C# (ASP.NET Core Razor Pages) SQL query, works fine in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have the following parameterized SQL query, which inserts data into a table, gets the (automatically incremented) Id value of the new row, and then inserts that new value into another table:

```
DECLARE @engId_newtable TABLE(engId INT); 
DECLARE @engId_new INT; 

INSERT INTO eng (locationTypeId, engNumb, projectId, engTypeId, capacity, cylNo, employeeId, bore, stroke, crankOffset, rodLength, cr, crankThrow, pinOffset, engDesc) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.engId INTO @engId_newtable 
SELECT a.locationTypeId, @engNumb, b.projectId, c.engTypeId, @capacity, @cylNo, d.employeeId, @bore, @stroke, @crankOffset, @rodLength, @cr, @crankThrow, @pinOffset, @engDesc 
FROM dbo.locationType AS a,dbo.project AS b,dbo.engType AS c,dbo.employees AS d 
WHERE a.locationType = @locationType AND b.projectCode = @projectCode AND b.engineType = @engineType AND c.engType = @engType AND d.userName = @userName ;

SELECT @engId_new = engId FROM @engId_newtable; 

INSERT INTO oil (engId, oilQuantity, oilTypeId) 
SELECT @engId_new, @oilQuantity, a.oilTypeId 
FROM dbo.oilType AS a 
WHERE a.oilManufacturer = @oilManufacturer AND a.oilRange = @oilRange AND a.oilGrade = @oilGrade ;
```

The query works perfectly when executed in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), but when I try to run it using my ASP.NET Core C# (Razor Pages) project, it fails with the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot insert the value NULL into
>   column 'engId', table 'TestEng.dbo.oil'; column does not allow nulls.
>   INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.'

So it appears that the `OUTPUT INSERTED` command is not working. I have also tried using `SELECT @engId_new = SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, and even `@@IDENTITY`, but they also return null and give the same error.

I have similar queries (using `OUTPUT INSERTED`) in other areas of my project, which work fine. This query was also working correctly until earlier today, when we changed the server the SQL database is running on - maybe I need to change some database/table settings?

Any help is much appreciated, I'm really at a loss here. Thanks.

---

EDIT: Showing how the query is executed

Query is built programatically - I know the query building functions work as all my other queries work fine - the query I'm trying to execute is exactly as shown here (it is returned by the query builder as a single string):

```
"DECLARE @engId_newtable TABLE(engId INT); DECLARE @engId_new INT; INSERT INTO eng (locationTypeId, engNumb, projectId, engTypeId, capacity, cylNo, employeeId, bore, stroke, crankOffset, rodLength, cr, crankThrow, pinOffset, engDesc) OUTPUT INSERTED.engId INTO @engId_newtable SELECT a.locationTypeId, @engNumb, b.projectId, c.engTypeId, @capacity, @cylNo, d.employeeId, @bore, @stroke, @crankOffset, @rodLength, @cr, @crankThrow, @pinOffset, @engDesc FROM dbo.locationType AS a,dbo.project AS b,dbo.engType AS c,dbo.employees AS d WHERE a.locationType = @locationType AND b.projectCode = @projectCode AND b.engineType = @engineType AND c.engType = @engType AND d.userName = @userName ;SELECT @engId_new = engId FROM @engId_newtable; INSERT INTO oil (engId, oilTypeId) SELECT @engId_new, a.oilTypeId FROM dbo.oilType AS a WHERE a.oilManufacturer = @oilManufacturer AND a.oilRange = @oilRange AND a.oilGrade = @oilGrade ;"
```

Query Execution function, called from razor page model, query and connection passed as parameters:

```
public void ExecuteVoid(SqlConnection con, string query, List<SqlColumn> columns, List<SqlFilter> filters)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        Parameterize(cmd, columns, filters);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

The `Parameterize` function just adds all the relevant parameters to the query. Again, like the query builder function, I know it works because all my other queries execute as expected.

---

EDIT 2: SQL Server Profiler

Shown below is an image showing all the events relevant to this query that I can see in SQL Server Profiler:

[image: SQL Server Profiler Events]

All parts of the query are written out as expected, all parameters are present, but the query still fails.

Comment: You can do this in c#, most likely you just have it wrong. Show the code?

Comment: What queries (SP statements) and exceptions does SQL profiler show?

Comment: @Arvo SQL profiler shows a single event of event class `RPC:Completed` with text data `exec sp_executesql` and then the query. EDIT: Also get exception `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'engId', table 'TestEng.dbo.oil'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.`

Comment: Choose more events in profiler, like exception, sp statement started, sp statement completed - this way you should see more. And - does your query in profiler look exactly like it should?

Comment: @Arvo see my second edit to the question

Comment: Ah, seems that your table `eng`, column `engId` has lost its identity property? Are you operating in correct database? :)

Comment: @Arvo Definitely on the correct db - can I re-add the id property to the columns somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem! I was using `HttpContext.Session.GetString` to get the value of a `WHERE` clause in my first query (to the `eng` table). I had changed the name of the string elsewhere in my code, and forgotten to change it in the query. So, the problem had nothing to do with SQL at all, really.
I can say that SQL server profiler was crucial in finding this error, so if you're having trouble with parameterized sql queries Visual C#, look over your queries there and you may highlight some unseen issues.